# Mysql Match Against query not returning exact resutls

Tags: mysql

we have the following query:

```
SELECT video . * , u.name, u.username, p.avatar
FROM jos_hwdvidsvideos AS video
WHERE video.public_private = 'public'
AND MATCH (
    title, tags, description
)
AGAINST (
    'matthew:13-44-46'
)
AND video.published =1
AND video.approved = "yes"
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The only problem is that it would be returning results where the title, tags, or description matches `matthew:13-44-46` but it returns anything that has `matthew` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html):

> If you want to change the set of characters that are considered word characters, you can do so in several ways, as described in the following list. After making the modification, you must rebuild the indexes for each table that contains any `FULLTEXT` indexes. Suppose that you want to treat the hyphen character (`'-'`) as a word character. Use one of these methods:
>
> - Modify the MySQL source: In `storage/myisam/ftdefs.h`, see the `true_word_char()` and `misc_word_char()` macros. Add `'-'` to one of those macros and recompile MySQL.
> - Modify a character set file: This requires no recompilation. The `true_word_char()` macro uses a “character type” table to distinguish letters and numbers from other characters. . You can edit the contents of the `<ctype><map>` array in one of the character set XML files to specify that `'-'` is a “letter.” Then use the given character set for your `FULLTEXT` indexes. For information about the `<ctype><map>` array format, see [Section 10.3.1, “Character Definition Arrays”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/character-arrays.html).
> - Add a new collation for the character set used by the indexed columns, and alter the columns to use that collation. For general information about adding collations, see [Section 10.4, “Adding a Collation to a Character Set”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/adding-collation.html). For an example specific to full-text indexing, see [Section 12.9.7, “Adding a Collation for Full-Text Indexing”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/full-text-adding-collation.html).

Alternatively, you could perform an exact-phrase seach [`IN BOOLEAN MODE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-boolean.html):

```
MATCH (title, tags, description) AGAINST ('"matthew:13-44-46"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```